# MariaDB: sum values from JSON

Tags: json, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I'd like to sum up certain values from a JSON snippet following this example data:

```json
set @json='
{
  "items": [
    {
      "a": {
        "a_amount": "0.0020095"
      },
      "b": {
        "b_amount": "0.0004"
      }
    },
    {
      "a": {
        "a_amount": "0.02763081"
      },
      "b": {
        "b_amount": "0.0055"
      }
    }
  ]
}';
```

I need to sum all `a.a_amount` and all `b.b_amount` independantly, so I'd like to do something like `SUM(a.a_amount)` and `SUM(b.b_amount)`.

But I haven't gotten any further than extracting the respective values like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.items[*].a.a_amount') AS sum_a,
       JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.items[*].b.b_amount') AS sum_b;
```

| sum_a | sum_b |
| --- | --- |
| ["0.0020095", "0.02763081"] | ["0.0004", "0.0055"] |

I've fiddled around with `JSON_EXTRACT()`, `JSON_VALUE()` and even the `ha_connect` plugin but still couldn't come up with SQL code that would give me the sums I need.

Who can help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using a DOUBLE conversion along with *Recursive CTE* through use of `JSON_EXTRACT()` function such as

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
SELECT 0 i
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1 i
  FROM cte
 WHERE i + 1 <= ( SELECT JSON_LENGTH(json) FROM j )  
)
SELECT SUM(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$.items[',i,'].a.a_amount')) AS DOUBLE)) AS sum_a,
       SUM(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$.items[',i,'].b.b_amount')) AS DOUBLE)) AS sum_b
  FROM cte,
       j
```

| sum_a | sum_b |
| --- | --- |
| 0.02964031 | 0.0059 |

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=87ebb3076713a2fdbdcca837e4a505f5)</kbd>

Comment: That's impressive and beautiful. I didn't even know about recursion in CTEs. Thanks for sharing. Only I suppose it should be `...(SELECT JSON_LENGTH(@json, '$.items') FROM j ) ...` instead of `... (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(json) FROM j ) ...`. I mean your code works kind of accidentally because `JSON_LENGTH(json)` will always return 1 with my example JSON, regardless of the number of items it might contain.

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON Table](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/functions/JSON_TABLE/) function could help you. Here a small example with your data. Maybe you must play a little bit with the data types.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(a_amount), 
  SUM(b_amount) 
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM 
  JSON_TABLE(@json, '$.items[*]' COLUMNS(
      a_amount FLOAT PATH '$.a.a_amount',
      b_amount FLOAT PATH '$.b.b_amount'
    )
  ) as items
) as temp;
```

| SUM(a_amount) | SUM(b_amount) |
| --- | --- |
| 0.029640309745445848 | 0.005899999960092828 |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bjSFR6s5kj9tQM35bXPm3N/0)

Comment: Nice solution but JSON_TABLE was added to MariaDB in version 10.6.0. Btw, replace FLOAT with DOUBLE for exact results.

Comment: Unfortunately no option for me to update the DBMS